# Do all ATmega32u4 QFN ground pads need to be connected?

Tags: pcb-design, ground, grounding, qfn

A QFN chip I'm working with (atmega32u4) has multiple pads connected to ground, see the picture. Is it really necessary to connect all these pads? Could I say omit one or is it really bad practice? Would it be a big deal?
[image]

Comment: Short answer - absolutely :)

Comment: Generally, but this is determined by the specific chip, not the package.  Doubly so when you talk about a possible ground pad on the underside of the QFN (there are actually examples there where the manufacturer has come to recommend leaving that floating)

Comment: @ChrisStratton I believe you, but... can you name even one, off hand? I'd like to see how that's written up. I haven't every encountered a case, yet. But my experience is admittedly limited.

Comment: You have an equal amount of +VCC pins. Think about that for a while. Then google "atmega inside" and see how the pins are  connected to the die.

Comment: @jonk nRF24L01+ though now that I look again, it may have been that the data sheet said not to connect the center pad, and later they said it was okay to.  Of course that's an entirely different part than this question about, and only useful to demonstrate that "QFN" from the original title doesn't imply much by itself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. Having worked on the IC FAB side of things doing in-situ temperature measurements of wafers (and not worrying about the packaging), I was struggling with the idea of the cost of wire bonding and pins and adding pins that aren't used. In my limited experience, there may be a number of grounding pads on the die and there may be fewer grounding pins on the package. But it would be pretty unusual to then decide to pay to bond a pad to a pin, test it, and then say "well, don't use this anyway." ;) That's not something that should happen often, anyway. I was very curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple GND pins serves several purposes:

- Lower ground inductance. In this case, the pins will be internally connected, and not connecting one to GND will worsen performance, but it could still work. Maybe. I mean, probably. I mean, I could stop my bicycle when one brake cable snapped, so why do I need two brakes, eh?
- Isolate AGND from DGND. In this case, they are not connected internally, and omitting the GND via from AGND means your ADC will not work at all, or just burn.

Are vias that expensive? Last time I checked they weren't, really...

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have no use for the ADC in this case, though I'll still be connecting it to ground. I guess I'll just be safe and connect em' all together.

Comment: I recall recently seeing an indication that there are key parts of an ATmega other than what you would think of as the ADC, which derive their power from that supply pin.  Sorry I can't remember where.

Comment: Yeah, and it's only 3 GND pins, not that hard to add 3 vias, right?